# FindHDF5 picks static library while shared one is requested

Tags: cmake, hdf5

I have compiled hdf5-1.8.21 to have both static and shared libraries. In the project I use

```
set (HDF5_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES FALSE)
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
```

to just select the shared library version but it does not work. It contradicts with the documentation in FindHDF5.cmake. I do not know the reason for it.

Comment: Which target of `hdf5` do you link with your project?

Comment: @c4pQ can you explain a bit more? In the command above the target is not set?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure do `target_link_libraries` for you binary/library with static HDF5 library target [HDF5_LIB_TARGET](https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5/blob/8b54201509257e3d2cd968dfae8bcda1ddef4988/CMakeLists.txt#L183) and not [HDF5_LIBSH_TARGET](https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5/blob/8b54201509257e3d2cd968dfae8bcda1ddef4988/CMakeLists.txt#L199)